# Hyperlink backslash auto converted to slash

Tags: ms-word

I have an issue with hyperlink, recently I have wanted to add a hyperlink but when I addet it the backshlashes in hyperlink automaticly changed from **..\abc\bvcx** to **../abc/bvcx**

Comment: Because that will be your system's path separator, and that is how hyperlinks work. Is it opening OK? then what is the problem?

Comment: @Rahul it isn't working OK. Hiperlinks that I created earliend have a proper path, but now they auto change and I don't know why. I need the ..\adb\ path.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is not opening, What is the error message. What is the operating system you are using, is changing the path separator manually works?

Comment: it is not working because the slashes are auto converted.  I use win7; when I edit the hyperlink and save it the slashes also are auto changed.

Comment: lukesky, Hyperlinks have forward slashes, not backslashes. File paths on the computer have backslashes. Word will change backslashes to forward slashes in order to make the hyperlink work. If the hyperlink is *not* working then there is some other problem. **Please note**: This question is off-topic on StackOverflow. See the guidelines for asking questions in the [help].

Answer (score 1):

Is the document where the odd behavior is occurring NOT a *.doc, but some 
other file format? Or was it originally created as something other than a WORD 
document? Otherwise try to start the Word document is safe mode. Hope it will work.

Try this:

1. Click **File**>**Options**>**Advanced**.
2. Under **General**, click **Web Options**>Files
3. Uncheck the **Update links on save** check box.

Comment: document is in .doc format and even in safe mode backshlasch is changed

Comment: so, is the problem with a particular document (or documents) and not generally with Word?

Comment: in general witd Word because I have tested in several docks.

Comment: @Eio: this is not the answer. You can comment such thinggs

Comment: @Rahul, True but trying to get some more information about the problem. The question contains just little information. BTW im new so i will comment next time, sorry.

Comment: Oh, Sorry. I didn't see your repo. Untill you get 50 you might not be able to do that. I am deleting my comments.

Comment: @lukesky mysterious problem for me, seems like something is wrong in your standard language or something when u save the document. Don't know the answer for now.